# Entity Framework 4.2 Code First - Automatically generate guid on client / not db on entity save

Tags: c#, entity-framework, auto-generate

How can I automatically generate a new guid on every entity save?  I don't want a db generated Guid.  I want to generate a new guid on the client, but don't want to have to set the guid on every business logic method.  I tried this in my extended DbContext class:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<EntityBase<Guid>>()
            .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added))
        {
            if (entry.Entity.Id == Guid.Empty)
            {
                entry.Entity.Id = MiscHelper.NewGuidComb();
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

but I'm getting InvalidOperationException Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.ToList()` to the end of the query to create a copied list of the entry references:

```
foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<EntityBase<Guid>>()
            .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).ToList())
```

This copied collection won't be modified and the exception shouldn't occur.